# R - Add a column from values of others dataframes with conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, conditional-statements

My dataframe is :

```
dataMDS <- data.frame(FID=c(1,1), IID=c("CD03577","50016"), SOL=c(0,0), C1=c(0.00332472,-0.00154285))
> dataMDS
   FID      IID  SOL            C1
1    1  CD03577    0    0.00332472
2    1    50016    0   -0.00154285
```

I would like to add a new column `plates` with values from 2 others dataframe :

```
platesRAC <- data.frame(V1=c(1,1), V2=c("CD03577","CD0371"), V3=c("2011-01-12_RAC1","2011-01-27_RAC5"))
> platesRAC
  V1      V2                    V3
1  1 CD03577       2011-01-12_RAC1
2  1  CD0371       2011-01-27_RAC5

platesDESIR <- data.frame(V1=c(1,1,1), V2=c("50015","50016","50017"), V3=c("2011-11-23_DESIR9","2011-11-23_DESIR9","2011-11-23_DESIR8"))
> platesDESIR
  V1    V2                 V3
1  1 50015  2011-11-23_DESIR9
2  1 50016  2011-11-23_DESIR9
3  1 50017  2011-11-23_DESIR8
```

I would like to get the value in V3 from `platesRAC` OR `platesDESIR` when `V2 == IID` and add this value in a new column `plates` in `dataMDS`.

I tried with merge :

```
new <- merge(x = dataMDS, y = platesRAC, by.x = "IID", by.y = 'V2', all = TRUE)

   FID      IID  SOL            C1   V1               V3
1    1  CD03577    0    0.00332472    1  2011-01-12_RAC1
2    1    50016    0   -0.00154285   NA             <NA>
```

And of course I have NA values because `IID 50016` is in `platesDESIR` and not in `platesRAC`. I don't know how to do an OR | to don't have NA values.

Also, I don't want the `V1` column after merging, just the `V3` column rename in `plates`

The results I would like to have :

```
   FID      IID  SOL            C1              plates
1    1  CD03577    0    0.00332472     2011-01-12_RAC1
2    1    50016    0   -0.00154285   2011-11-23_DESIR9
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: try merging with `y=rbind(platesRAC, platesDESIR)`

Comment: Please make your examples reproducible and add expected output. This makes it much easier for others to help you

Comment: It doesn't work with `rbind` because my dataframes have different lengths so I also have NA values this way. 
I added code to reproduce my dataframes and the result expected, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Just use `complete.cases`, i.e. `final <- merge(x = dataMDS, y = rbind(platesRAC, platesDESIR), by.x = "IID", by.y = 'V2', all = TRUE); final[complete.cases(final),]`

Comment: Is this working for you ? I still have NA values with complete cases with the same exact example. And I think it's because some V2 values are not in dataMDS$IID. I want the length of dataMDS at the end and not the length of rbind(platesRAC, platesDESIR).

Comment: `merge` with `complete.cases` works fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a merge but a match after binded platesRAC and platesDESIR :

```
bindRACDESIR = rbind(platesRAC, platesDESIR)
dataMDS$plates <- bindRACDESIR$V3[match(dataMDS$IID,bindRACDESIR$V2)]
```

And the result is :

```
   FID      IID  SOL            C1              plates
1    1  CD03577    0    0.00332472     2011-01-12_RAC1
2    1    50016    0   -0.00154285   2011-11-23_DESIR9
```